# Skip web site creation on upgrade

Tags: iis, wix

I have an installer that deploys IIS application, creating Application Pool and Web Site under Default Web Site folder. During the upgrade, the web site is being removed and so is the application pool, and then being re-created when newer version is deployed. I want to replace ONLY the physical files of the web site during upgrade without touching IIS configurations. This is the snippet on how IIS is being handled during installation and upgrade:

```
<Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="WEBAPPLICATIONS">
    <Component Id="cmpWebApplicationsWebAppPool" Guid="{SOME-GUID}" KeyPath="yes" Win64="yes">
        <util:User Id="iisWAAppPoolUser" CreateUser="no" Name="[PROP_USER]" Domain="[PROP_DOMAIN]"  Password="[PROP_PASSWORD]"/>
        <iis:WebAppPool Id="WAAppPool"
            Name="$(var.ProductDisplayName)Apps"
            Identity="other"
            User="iisWAAppPoolUser"
            IdleTimeout="0"
            ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"
            ManagedPipelineMode="Classic"
            RecycleMinutes="0"
            QueueLimit="32676" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="cmpWebApplications" Guid="{SOME-OTHER-GUID}" KeyPath="yes" Win64="yes">
        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="WAVirtualDir" Alias="$(var.ProductDisplayName)Apps" Directory="WEBAPPLICATIONS" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
            <iis:WebDirProperties Id="WADirProperties" AnonymousAccess="yes" BasicAuthentication="no" WindowsAuthentication="no" />
            <iis:WebApplication Id="WAWebApplication" Name="$(var.ProductDisplayName)Apps" WebAppPool="WAAppPool" />
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```